# Getting Metamask account's balance using fromWei

Tags: web3js, balances, typescript, angular2

Using web3 javascript code to get selected account's balance in Metamask and show it in html,

```
web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
  if (err === null) { 
    App.account = account;
    $("#account").text(account);
    web3.eth.getBalance(account, function(err, balance) {
      if (err === null) {
        $("#accountBalance").text(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and now I'm using angular 4 trying to convert above code to typescript.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const myBettingArtifact = 
require('../../../build/contracts/Test.json');
declare var window: any;
...
account: any;
accounts: any;
web3: any;
balance: number;

this.web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accs) => {      
  if (err != null || accs.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  this.accounts = accs;
  this.account = this.accounts[0];

  this.web3.eth.getBalance(this.account, function(err, balance) {
    this.balance = this.web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH"        
  });
});
```

However I get an error

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromWei' of undefined

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, `this` is not the same inside the anonymous callback function you're passing to `getBalance`. Try replacing it with a [fat arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html), that binds the outer `this` value to the inner scope.

```
this.web3.eth.getBalance(this.account, (err, balance) => {
  this.balance = this.web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH"
});
```

Comment: could you provide more code? I always get nil/null for `account` variable

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov the code I posted is from OP. Are you running a ganache or testrpc? You need a node with accounts.

Comment: @martriay ganache works - it shows a list of wallets I can use. So that way works. But what to do with metamask? It shows one account address too but the code above doesn't have an access to it

Comment: I am not able to install web3 in angular 5

Answer (score 1):

web3.eth.getBalance(this.userWalletAddress, (err, balance) => {
this.userBalance = **web3.utils.fromWei**(balance, "ether") + " ETH"
});